# Can iptables DNAT multiple times in sequence?

Tags: networking, iptables

The following iptables rules already exist on node A:

```
$ iptables -t nat -nvL PREROUTING
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 4 packets, 200 bytes)
...
   64  3840 DNAT       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            100.0.1.10         to:100.0.0.10
```

I added one more DNAT rule:

```
$ iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 100.0.2.10 -j DNAT --to-destination 100.0.1.10
$ iptables -t nat -nvL PREROUTING
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 4 packets, 200 bytes)
...
    3   252 DNAT       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            100.0.2.10         to:100.0.1.10
   64  3840 DNAT       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            100.0.1.10        to:100.0.0.10
```

I hope that when node A receives a packet with a destination address of 100.0.2.10, it will perform two DNAT conversions to 100.0.0.10. But in fact, iptables only did one DNAT to convert 100.0.2.10 to 100.0.1.10.
How do i achieve this goal?

Maybe you will ask why I don't just DNAT 100.0.2.10 to 100.0.0.10? Because the logic to get 100.0.0.10 is complex, this rule was created by another application. If you know kube-proxy, you may know that kube-proxy in iptables mode will DNAT service IP to pod IP. I want to create a globalIP, first DNAT to service ip, and then reuse the rules of kube-proxy, DNAT to pod IP.